# Load images as scolling down page isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading

I'm using this code on my site to load images as I scroll down the page:  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/

You can see where I'm trying to use it here:  http://www.easythemepro.com/themes.php

I've added this Javascript code into my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
!function(window){
  var $q = function(q, res){
        if (document.querySelectorAll) {
          res = document.querySelectorAll(q);
        } else {
          var d=document
            , a=d.styleSheets[0] || d.createStyleSheet();
          a.addRule(q,'f:b');
          for(var l=d.all,b=0,c=[],f=l.length;b<f;b++)
            l[b].currentStyle.f && c.push(l[b]);

          a.removeRule(0);
          res = c;
        }
        return res;
      }
    , addEventListener = function(evt, fn){
        window.addEventListener
          ? this.addEventListener(evt, fn, false)
          : (window.attachEvent)
            ? this.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn)
            : this['on' + evt] = fn;
      }
    , _has = function(obj, key) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
      }
    ;

  function loadImage (el, fn) {
    var img = new Image()
      , src = el.getAttribute('data-src');
    img.onload = function() {
      if (!! el.parent)
        el.parent.replaceChild(img, el)
      else
        el.src = src;

      fn? fn() : null;
    }
    img.src = src;
  }

  function elementInViewport(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()

    return (
       rect.top    >= 0
    && rect.left   >= 0
    && rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    )
  }

    var images = new Array()
      , query = $q('img.lazy')
      , processScroll = function(){
          for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            if (elementInViewport(images[i])) {
              loadImage(images[i], function () {
                images.splice(i, i);
              });
            }
          };
        }
      ;
    // Array.prototype.slice.call is not callable under our lovely IE8 
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
      images.push(query[i]);
    };

    processScroll();
    addEventListener('scroll',processScroll);

}(this);?
</script>
```

And I'm using this format to show images:

```
<img src="img/blank.png" data-src="demo/wp-content/themes/Alfina/screenshot.png" width="300" height="225" class="lazy">
```

You can see where this code is working on a demo page at `http://css-tricks.com/examples/LazyLoading/` but I can't figure out what's causing it to not work on my page...

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your function with this script

```
$(function() {
  var $q = function(q, res){
        if (document.querySelectorAll) {
          res = document.querySelectorAll(q);
        } else {
          var d=document
            , a=d.styleSheets[0] || d.createStyleSheet();
          a.addRule(q,'f:b');
          for(var l=d.all,b=0,c=[],f=l.length;b<f;b++)
            l[b].currentStyle.f && c.push(l[b]);

          a.removeRule(0);
          res = c;
        }
        return res;
      }
    , addEventListener = function(evt, fn){
        window.addEventListener
          ? this.addEventListener(evt, fn, false)
          : (window.attachEvent)
            ? this.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn)
            : this['on' + evt] = fn;
      }
    , _has = function(obj, key) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
      }
    ;

  function loadImage (el, fn) {
    var img = new Image()
      , src = el.getAttribute('data-src');
    img.onload = function() {
      if (!! el.parent)
        el.parent.replaceChild(img, el)
      else
        el.src = src;

      fn? fn() : null;
    }
    img.src = src;
  }

  function elementInViewport(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()

    return (
       rect.top    >= 0
    && rect.left   >= 0
    && rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    )
  }

    var images = new Array()
      , query = $q('img.lazy')
      , processScroll = function(){
          for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            if (elementInViewport(images[i])) {
              loadImage(images[i], function () {
                images.splice(i, i);
              });
            }
          };
        }
      ;
    // Array.prototype.slice.call is not callable under our lovely IE8 
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
      images.push(query[i]);
    };

    processScroll();
    addEventListener('scroll',processScroll);

  });
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GZzLd/)

Comment: Just replaced it with that and it loads the first 2 rows but nothing after that, you can see it here:  http://www.easythemepro.com/themes.php

Comment: Still not working on my end, sorry.  You can see what it did here:  http://www.easythemepro.com/themes.php

Comment: i think bug in script try these http://toddmotto.com/echo-js-simple-javascript-image-lazy-loading/

Comment: Tried that and got the same error where it just loaded every other image for the first few rows.  I've reverted back to the code you posted where it shows at least the first 6 but doesn't appear to recognize when being scrolled.